# SQL Query in python file shows up as "COLUMNS" instead of "VALUES"

Tags: python, sql, azure

I am very new at this, and im trying my best but i simply cant see where im f...ing up =(

I have made an SQL Query in my python file. I want to write to my Azure database table --> make a new row
the query is this:

```
SQLQuery ="""
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Input_Table_Test] 
                VALUES ("""+(respons['symbol'])+""",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);"""
```

The "respons ['symbol']" is a dynamic JSON element and im trying to get the key uploaded into the query
(in this case its 'SMG') - dont worry about all the 1s, its just because so it fits the table.

When im running the query from my python file im getting this error message:
('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'SMG'.")

but im not trying to write to the columns, im trying to make row/values.

I tried editing the query to see if something else was wrong but no. If you replace "(respons['symbol'])" with a 1 it works perfectly. i dont know where to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` is an integer, which does not need to be quoted.

But `SMG` is (presumably) intended to be a string, and thus would need quotes around it like so `'SMG'`.

But because you didn't quote it, it's being interpreted as the name of some other column in the table.  And of course you don't have a column named that, so you get the error.

Put quotes around `SMG`.

Comment: Thank you, that works - got confused by all the quotes :D